# Run one gulp4 task on multiple folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, glob

I tried to run the gulp task to multiple folders
but I have an issue

Actually, I run a single function(task) and  there is no   issue

```
const componentsPaths = glob.sync(comSrcPath + '/*/');
function conactComJs(path) { 
    // concat all js components 
    return src([path + '**/01_*.js', path + '**/02_*.js', path + '**/03_*.js', path + '**/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('init.js'))
        .pipe(dest(path + 'js'));
}

 function conactAllComJs() {
        let stream;
        // // work on each folder separately
        componentsPaths.forEach(function (path) {
            stream = conactComJs(path);
        });
        return stream;
  }; 
exports.components = series(conactAllComJs());
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered
I called to task by  wrong way

```
exports.components = series(conactAllComJs);
```